# Will Sun/Oracle HDD work in a non-Sun system?

Tags: oracle, sas, sun

I know that Sun/Oracle-branded HDD's have a modified firmware, but can these drives work in a non-Sun system?
Specifically Sun ST32000SSUN2.0T (which are 2 TB 7200 RPM Seagate Constellation ES drives) and LSISAS2108-based or similar  6Gb/s SAS controller.

I don't have these drives by hand, so I can't test this configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, modified HDDs (firmware or sector sizes) work flawlessly in 'generic' systems.

Firmware mods may be necessary to ensure perfect compatibility, larger sector sizes are necessary in large storage arrays that need to add metadata to each sector. Both methods are also used for customer tie-in.

However, all HDDs should still be compatible with the standards and should work in all systems that work with generic drives. HDDs with larger sectors will have a slightly reduced capacity though (in case you want to add them to an existing array).

Comment: I never worried about HP, Dell, IBM, etc. But I heard somewhere that Sun drives are special and can't work in a non-Sun system. The problem is the fact that I can't try these drives before I pay for them, and once payed, they can't be returned. If they won't work, I don't know what to do with them.